# Изменение birth date файла

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, posix, touch

Как изменить `birth date` файла?

Изменить время модификации можно с помощью `touch -m`, подобной опции для `birth date` не нашёл.

Comment: [никак](https://askubuntu.com/q/918300/416190)

Comment: Прочитать можно. Вот тут показано как http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/

Comment: @becouse а изменить?

Comment: @stas Возникает вопрос зачем? Скорее всего простыми средствами никак ибо это системная часть ФС.

Comment: Переименовать старый, создать новый с именем старого, скопировать данные со старого в новый и удалить старый. Но вот путь к ячейку памяти будет уже другой.  Если найдете способ кинуть его в старую ячейку по-тихому - будете почивать на лаврах.

Comment: @V.March таким образом, `birth date` изменится на текущее время, а хотелось бы на произвольное изменить. Хотя если перевести часы перед всем этим...

Comment: Хотите читонуть что-то что имеет ограниченный период действия?

Comment: Это тоже Ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/421796 ?

Comment: @V.March не задавал вопросов ближайшее время. Хочу изменить `birth date` на произвольную дату или хотя бы на дату, не превышающую текущую

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить. Например с таким запросом. У меня вылезла первая же ссылка на https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file

Comment: Или  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118577/changing-a-files-date-created-and-last-modified-attributes-to-another-file

Comment: @V.March в приведенных ссылках не нашёл ответа на вопрос

Comment: Раз уж Вам тема ковыряния линукса близка, то попробуйте задать этот же вопрос на более специализированой ветке SO -   https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @V.March [задал](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556040/385314), кому интересно

Comment: @stas Отлично. Как говорится: одна голова хорошо, а со стековерфлоу лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Это нельзя сделать в ext4, "Birth date" задаётся при создании файла и не может меняться.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556047/385314

Answer (score 0):

Само понятие "Birth date" по отношению к файлу является **бессмысленным** и в линухе не используется. Простейший пример.Вчера мы сосздали файл *a.txt*. Сегодня выполняем команду:

```
cp a.txt b.txt
```

и какая "Birth date" должна быть у *b.txt? Сегодняшная? Вы уверены? Ну да - ведь это же **новый** файл, который только что родился. А если я выполню такую команду:

```
mv a.txt b.txt
```

Какая "Birth date" должна быть у *b.txt*? Уже не очевидно? Вроде - вчерашняя. Ведь это же **старый** файл, который мы просто переименовали. У него должна изменится только дата модификации, но не рождения - так? С точки зрения FAT16 всё так. Просто изменили строчку в таблице распределения файлов. Сам файл не изменился. С точки зрения люниха - всё не так очевидно. Если файлы *a.txt* и *b.txt* расположены внутри **одной** ФС, то будет изменена только структура инодов. А вот если они расположены на **разных** ФС, то произойдёт физическое перемещение файлов. Это можно считать актом творения?

А если я последнюю операцию выполню в два шага (как она на самом деле и делается):

```
cp a.txt b.txt
rm a.txt
```

Тогда какая "Birth date" должна быть у *b.txt*?  как то уже совсем **не** очевидно.

Мораль: понятие "Birth date" можно более-менее адекватно использовать в ФС типа FAT16, в которых файл - это кусок прострнства на носителе. И дата создания файла совпадает с датой выделения этого самого прострнства.

Почему такой подход "не катит" для линуха? По многим причинам:

1. В линухе есть файлы-устройства, которые с диском вообще никак не связаны.
2. Есть огромное количество псевдофайлов, тоже с диском никак не связанных.
3. Существуют линки на файлы, которые могут появляться и исчезать совершенно независимо от файлов, на которые они ссылаются.
4. Даже самые обычные дисковые файлы связаны с дисковым пространством не напрямую, а через т.н. иноды, что делает связь файл <-> дисковое пространство довольно запутанной.
5. Наконец (самое важное) - это просто бессмысленное понятие, который каждый волен толковать как ему вздумается.